# How can I use the result of a nested function?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

I have a homework where I'm creating a program in Python 3.7.x where I need to calculate the number of different paths form point A to B. Now I'm doing a simple Tkinter GUI where it create a square grid of buttons using a user input (from 1 to 8)(Please see image below)[image]

Then I created a function where I save the coordinates from the first clicked button and the second, which is the nested function:

````
          ``` startPoint = None
              endPoint = None
              clicks = 0

              def SaveCoord(x,y):
                 def returnFunction():
                    global clicks
                    if clicks == 0:
                       global startPoint
                       startPoint = [x,y]
                       print(startPoint)
                       clicks+=1
                    elif clicks == 1:
                       global endPoint
                       endPoint = [x,y]
                       print(endPoint)
                       clicks+=1
                    else:
                       print("You have already selected your points!")

                   return returnFunction ```
````

In order to calculate the number of paths, i need to get the difference of X's and Y's
which are stored as `startPoint` and `endPoint` lists. How can I do that ? I'm not able to access `returnFunction()` values.Every time I try to do so i get a `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error

If needed I can post the whole code

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems here:

1) You aren't actually invoking `returnFunction`, just referencing the function in your return statement. Change that line to `return returnFunction()`

2) `returnFunction` doesn't actually return anything, it just prints, so even if you were invoking it the return value would be `None.` Update it to return the values you're looking to reference later on in addition to or instead of printing them.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are trying to use these functions such that `SaveCoord` returns a new function you can call later, you'd reference it like this `newFunc = SaveCoord(1,2)` and then call `newFunc()` or `SaveCoord(1,2)()` and store the results in a variable. The `returnFunction` name only exists within the scope of `saveCoord` so you can't reference it by that name later on. Either way, `returnFunction` still needs to actually return something to work as you're expecting it to.